# How to use javascript request to dynamoDB?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to use the following code for a request to dynamoDB:

```
var result = dynamodb.getItem(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else {
    console.log(data);           // successful response
  }
});
```

and subsequently use the result. However, I don't see how to make use of the `result`. From this object, there seems not to be a `result.getAttribute(firstName)` or similar way to get e.g. a string from the result.
How can I make use of the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dynamodb.getItem` function call is executing asynchronously (via Ajax) - that's why the second part of the function call contains a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function): `function(err, data){}`.

If you're looking to query the response/results of call, you'll need to use the `data` property being returned by aforementioned callback.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the JavaScript DynamoDB DocumentClient instead of interfacing with dynamodb directly.  It takes away a lot of the pain of typing your fields and what not.  Here are some useful links:

[SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html)

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-document-client.html)

[Blog Post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-amazon-dynamodb-document-client-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/)

The last one has a good example of how to use `getItem` and in your example inside of the callback where you're doing the `console.log(data);` you would do a `data.Item.firstName`